# nested if statement issues

Tags: javascript

okay the question is changed now, I am trying to do a calculator which shows you the day on which you were born then I found that my nested if-statement is not working

var userInformation = function (DD, MM, YY) {

return DD + MM + YY;

}

var DD = prompt("Enter your birthday:");

var MM = prompt("Enter your birthmonth:");

var YY = prompt("Enter your birthyear:");

var fullDate = (DD + ' /' + MM + ' /' + YY);

alert(fullDate);

```
var cc=parseInt(YY.toString().slice(0,2));

var myFunction=6+(parseInt(DD)+Math.floor(parseInt(YY.toString().substr(-2))/4));

var myNumbers;

var month;

month=[1,4,4,0,2,5,0,3];

function myReturn() {

    if (cc === 20) 
    {
        if (month === 01) {
            myNumbers = parseInt(1 + myFunction); 
        }
        else if (month === 02 || month === 03) {
            myNumbers = parseInt(4 + myFunction); 
        }
        else if (month === 04 || month === 07) {
            myNumbers = parseInt(0 + myFunction); 
        }
        else if (month === 05) {
            myNumbers = parseInt(2 + myFunction); 
        }
        else if (month === 06) { 
            myNumbers = parseInt(5 + myFunction); 
        }
        else if (month === 08) {
            myNumbers = parseInt(3 + myFunction); 
        }

      else {
      console.log('error'); 
       }; 
       }
      else {
      console.log('incorrect')
      }
      myReturn(month)


};
```

Comment: Please edit your question. People won't take the time if they see something like this.

Comment: @GentleSama thank you! so here it is again.

Comment: What I ment where those `enter code here`.

Comment: Where do you get that undefined? Where do you assign `YY` and `DD`? Also you're comparing array with numbers (variable `month`). Could you create working snippet (`[<>]` in editor)? Could you also explain what is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the entire stack trace? It looks to me like YY and DD are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You never define it. You initialized myNumbers like this

```
var myNumbers;
```

Which might not be null, but it has no value defined.
You then are defining a value for myNumbers based on conditions checking the value in an array called *month*. If none of those conditions are true then it never gets defined. The array *month* never equals any of those individual values. It is an array of those values, but never any of them individually. So none of those conditions are ever true, and the value remains undefined

Comment: glad if I can help. Feel free to mark as answer if it helped